# Maximum likelihood estimation for combination of parameters .

Tags: statistics

I just get confused about what's the MLE for $$
\frac{\mu}{\sigma^{2}}$$ where two parameters come from 
$$N\left(\mu, \sigma^{2}\right)$$

I only know the MLE for those things separately, but how am I able to calculate this thing?
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Look up 'invariance' property of MLE.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I don't really get it. 'Invariance' property of MLE says that "if $\widetilde{\theta}$ is an MLE... ". Can $\widetilde{\theta}$ there be a vector? say, $(\overline{X},S_n^2)$ ?

Comment: If both $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$ are unknown, MLE of $\theta=(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is $\hat\theta=(\overline X,S_n^2)$ (with usual notation). Here $\theta$ is a vector parameter, and naturally $\hat\theta$ is also a vector.